# Boost.Program_options syntax

Tags: c++, boost

I'm currently reading the Boost.Program_options tutorial.

Here is some of the code they introduce:

```
// Declare the supported options.
po::options_description desc("Allowed options");
desc.add_options()
    ("help", "produce help message")
    ("compression", po::value<int>(), "set compression level")
;
```

I understand the purpose behind this code, however the syntax confuses me. Are the indented lines arguments to a function? What is with the brackets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose `desc.get_options()` returns an object of a class that defines `operator()` which in turn returns the same object. So the indented lines are calls to this operator with arguments in brackets.

Looking at `boost/program_options/options_description.hpp` you can see that the class in question is `options_description_easy_init` which indeed has several `operator()`'s such as:

```
    options_description_easy_init&
    operator()(const char* name,
               const char* description);
```

Comment: This is typically referred to as a functor.

Comment: @Sam Miller: Right, a functor or a function object.